# Do All Drupal themes support subtheming?

Tags: 7, theming

I heard that only some themes can have a subtheme.
Is this true?

Comment: I would read https://drupal.org/node/225125 for *tons* of information on subthemes

Comment: And, you may want to consider renaming or rephrasing this question because the answer to the title is YES but the answer to the content is NO.

Comment: I would prefer changing title, as my answer starts with NO ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, of course it isn't true. **All themes can be subthemed.** Subtheming is a part of Drupal's core and themes cannot simply turn it down. You can always create a theme, name it's parent theme and override some CSS.

Fun starts when you want to override things from template.php, or if parent theme provides advanced configuration - not all themes are built in a way that makes subtheming **easy**. But even if it's not easy, it's not really blocked.

Comment: I was searching and i found some comments on templates that saying if the can have a subtheme and was answer as you can't make a subtheme with this template. This wasn't clear for me and i need it some help clear that out. Thank you again.

Comment: @Drupalizeme if theme author discourages subtheming or publish it with a licence that says you can't subtheme, then you probably shouldn't try as it may be a wasted effort (or legal problems). But it's still possible.